# Why does my JScrollPane appear apove my Panel untill i start scrolling over it?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

Here is the code for my GUI

The method loggedInView is the one i am having trouble with. The other methods are working properly.

It appears that the `JScrollPAne` appears over the panel it is supposed  to contain. So any element in the Panel is not visible until i begin scrolling over the `ScrollPAne`, than it becomes visible.

```
public class test1 {

    private JFrame frame;
    private final JPanel statePanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panel_1;
    private JButton btnLogIn;
    private JButton btnSignUp_1;
    private JPanel panel_3;
    private JTextField username;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;
    private JTextField pseudo;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    test1 window = new test1();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public test1() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblDearFriend = new JLabel("Dear Friend");
        lblDearFriend.setFont(new Font("Purisa", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblDearFriend.setBounds(175, 10, 113, 15);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblDearFriend);
        statePanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        statePanel.setBounds(346, 0, 104, 25);

        frame.getContentPane().add(statePanel);

        panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBounds(0, 26, 450, 244);
        entrypointview(panel_1);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(null);

        /*
        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        panel_2.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 3, true));
        panel_2.setBounds(0, 0, 103, 244);
        panel_1.add(panel_2);
        panel_2.setLayout(null);

        panel_3 = new JPanel();
        panel_3.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2, true));
        panel_3.setBounds(104, 0, 346, 244);
        panel_1.add(panel_3);
        */  
    }

    public void entrypointview(JPanel panel)

    {
        panel.setLayout(null);
        btnLogIn=new JButton("Log In");
        btnLogIn.setBounds(177, 80, 77, 25);
        btnLogIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
              {          
                  panel.removeAll();
                  panel.repaint();

                  frame.getContentPane().remove(panel);

                  viewLogin(panel);
                  //panel.validate();
                  panel.repaint();
                  panel.updateUI();

                  frame.getContentPane().add(panel);         
              }
            });
        panel.add(btnLogIn);

        btnSignUp_1 = new JButton("Sign Up");
        btnSignUp_1.setBounds(163, 117, 117, 25);
        btnSignUp_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
              {
                  panel.removeAll();
                  panel.repaint();

                  frame.getContentPane().remove(panel);

                  viewSignup(panel);
                //panel.validate();
                  panel.repaint();
                  panel.updateUI();

                  frame.getContentPane().add(panel);         
              }
            });
        panel.add(btnSignUp_1);
    }
    public void viewSignup(JPanel panel)
    {       
        username = new JTextField();
        username.setBounds(158, 48, 114, 19);
        panel.add(username);
        username.setColumns(10);

        pseudo = new JTextField();
        pseudo.setBounds(158, 110, 139, 19);
        panel.add(pseudo);
        pseudo.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username");
        lblUsername.setBounds(55, 50, 72, 15);
        panel.add(lblUsername);

        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        passwordField.setBounds(158, 79, 127, 19);
        panel.add(passwordField);

        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
        lblPassword.setBounds(65, 77, 70, 15);
        panel.add(lblPassword);

        JLabel lblSessionPseudo = new JLabel("Session Pseudo");
        lblSessionPseudo.setBounds(34, 104, 113, 15);
        panel.add(lblSessionPseudo);

        JButton btnSignUp = new JButton("Sign Up");
        btnSignUp.setBounds(158, 160, 117, 25);
        panel.add(btnSignUp);   
    }
    public void viewLogin(JPanel panel)
    {   
        panel.setLayout(null);
        username = new JTextField();
        username.setBounds(158, 48, 114, 19);
        panel.add(username);
        username.setColumns(10);

        pseudo = new JTextField();
        pseudo.setBounds(158, 110, 139, 19);
        panel.add(pseudo);
        pseudo.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username");
        lblUsername.setBounds(55, 50, 72, 15);
        panel.add(lblUsername);

        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        passwordField.setBounds(158, 79, 127, 19);
        panel.add(passwordField);

        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
        lblPassword.setBounds(65, 77, 70, 15);
        panel.add(lblPassword);

        JLabel lblSessionPseudo = new JLabel("Session Pseudo");
        lblSessionPseudo.setBounds(34, 104, 113, 15);
        panel.add(lblSessionPseudo);

        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Log In");
        btnLogin.setBounds(158, 160, 117, 25);
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
              {

                  panel.removeAll();
                  panel.repaint();

                  frame.getContentPane().remove(panel);

                  loggedInView(panel);
                  panel.validate();
                  panel.repaint();
                  panel.updateUI();
                  frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
              }
            });
        panel.add(btnLogin);        
    }
    public boolean  verifylogin(String username,String password)
    {
        return true; 

    }
    public boolean  challengepseudo(String pseudo)
    {
        return true; 

    }
    public boolean  challengeusername(String username)
    {
        return true;        
    }

    public void loggedInView(JPanel panel)
    {
        statePanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        //panel.setLayout(null);
        JPanel test=new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
        test.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 3, true));
        test.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 240);

        test=onlineUserToLabel(test,new CurrentUser());
        //panel.add(test);
        test.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,500));

        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(test);

        scroller.setSize(120, 240);

        scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        //scroller.setBorder(null);
        //panel_1.add(panel_2);

        panel.add(scroller);

        JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
        //panel_3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel_3,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        panel_3.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2, true));
        panel_3.setBounds(120, 0, 350, 244);

        ArrayList <AbstractMessage>list=new ArrayList <AbstractMessage>();
        for( int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
        list.add(new TextMessage("mike", "none", new Date(), "Hello World"));
        list.add(new TextMessage("none", "mike", new Date(), "Hey!"));
        }
        panel_3=messagesToPanel(panel_3,list,new CurrentUser());

        /*

        panel_3.add(messageToPanel(new TextMessage("mike", "none", new Date(), "Hello World"),new CurrentUser()));
        panel_3.add(messageToPanel(new TextMessage("none", "mike", new Date(), "Hey!"),new CurrentUser()));
        panel_3.add(messageToPanel(new TextMessage("mike", "none", new Date(), "Hello World"),new CurrentUser()));
        panel_3.add(messageToPanel(new TextMessage("none", "mike", new Date(), "Hey!"),new CurrentUser()));
        panel_3.add(messageToPanel(new TextMessage("mike", "none", new Date(), "Hello World"),new CurrentUser()));
        panel_3.add(messageToPanel(new TextMessage("none", "mike", new Date(), "Hey!"),new CurrentUser()));
        panel_3.add(messageToPanel(new TextMessage("mike", "none", new Date(), "Hello World"),new CurrentUser()));
        panel_3.add(messageToPanel(new TextMessage("none", "mike", new Date(), "Hey!"),new CurrentUser()));
        panel_3.add(messageToPanel(new TextMessage("mike", "none", new Date(), "Hello World"),new CurrentUser()));
        panel_3.add(messageToPanel(new TextMessage("none", "mike", new Date(), "Hey!"),new CurrentUser()));
        panel_3.add(messageToPanel(new TextMessage("mike", "none", new Date(), "Hello World"),new CurrentUser()));
        panel_3.add(messageToPanel(new TextMessage("none", "mike", new Date(), "Hey!"),new CurrentUser()));
        */
        JScrollPane scroller2 = new JScrollPane(panel_3);
        scroller2.setSize(330, 200);
            //scroller.setLocation(108, 12);
            scroller2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            scroller2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            //scroller2.setLocation(100, 20);
            scroller2.setBorder(null);

            scroller2.setBounds(120, 0, 330, 200);

            JScrollBar vertical2 = scroller2.getVerticalScrollBar();    
            vertical2.setMaximum(list.size()*40);

            vertical2.setValue(list.size()*40);         
            panel.add(scroller2);
    }
    public JPanel messageToPanel(AbstractMessage am,AbstractUserInfo user)
    {   

         JPanel messagePanel=null;

      switch(am.getType()) {
      case Text:
          messagePanel= new JPanel();
         messagePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,40));
         if(user.getUserid().equals(am.getSenderid()))
                {messagePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);}
         else {
            messagePanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
         }
         messagePanel.add(new JLabel(AbstractMessage.getTextMessage(am).getText_content()));
         break;       
      }               
    return messagePanel;
    }

    public JPanel onlineUserToLabel(JPanel panel,AbstractUserInfo a)
    {   
        //panel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, scroller);

          for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {

              JLabel lab = new JLabel(a.getPseudo().concat(" (").concat(a.getUserid().concat(") ")));
              lab.setBounds(0, i*20, 100, 20);
              panel.add(lab);
          }
        return panel;
        }   

    public JPanel messagesToPanel(JPanel panel,ArrayList<AbstractMessage> a,AbstractUserInfo user)
    {       
        //panel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, scroller);
            int i=0;
          for( AbstractMessage am :a)
          {
              JPanel mP=messageToPanel(am,user);
              mP.setBounds(0,40*i,350,40);
              i++;
              panel.add(mP);
          }

        return panel;
        }   
}
```

Comment: You should use a LayoutManager instead of calling setLayout(null).  Try using an IDE like NetBeans or Eclipse to design your UI

Comment: The two panels i am having trouble with do actually have a LayoutManager (Grid Layout)

Comment: Probably need to call validate() on the frame anytime you add/remove/setSize/setBounds on any subcomponent.  Again use LayoutManagers - this is sloppy code - the window will not adjust nicely to different screen sizes whereas a LayoutManger will work better.

Comment: Don't use updateUI(). That method is invoked internally when you do a Lood and Feel changes (which you are not doing). The revalidate() and repaint() needs to be done AFTER you add the component to the panel and you only need to do it once after all the components have been removed/added to the panel.

Comment: @camickr Thank you , problem solved